Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': repomd.xml parser error
when i use yum update i got:
    CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream                                  27 kB/s | 8.5 kB     00:00    
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': repomd.xml parser error: Parse error at line: 36 (Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 0 and head
)

App stream repo file is:
# CentOS-Stream-AppStream.repo
#
# The #####mirrorlist system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick current mirrors that are geographically
# close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates unless you are
# manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the #####mirrorlist does not work for you, you can try the commented out
# baseurl line instead.

[appstream]
name=CentOS Stream $releasever - AppStream
#####mirrorlist=http://#####mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$stream&arch=$base#arch&repo=AppStream&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/$contentdir/$stream/AppStream/$basearch/os/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial

logs in /var/log/dnf.log :
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 573, in load
    ret = self._repo.load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/libdnf/repo.py", line 397, in load
    return _repo.Repo_load(self)
libdnf._error.Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': repomd.xml parser error: Parse error at line: 36 (Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 0 and head
)

/var/log/dnf.librepo.log :
2024-08-30T02:34:14+0300 INFO Librepo version: 1.14.2 with CURL_GLOBAL_ACK_EINTR support (libcurl/7.61.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1k zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.6 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.20.2 (+libidn2/2.2.0) libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.33.0)
2024-08-30T02:34:14+0300 INFO Librepo version: 1.14.2 with CURL_GLOBAL_ACK_EINTR support (libcurl/7.61.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1k zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.6 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.20.2 (+libidn2/2.2.0) libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.33.0)
2024-08-30T02:34:14+0300 INFO Downloading: http://vault.centos.org/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml
2024-08-30T02:34:15+0300 WARNING WARNING: Repomd xml parser: Unknown element "html"

